# Cannot implicitly convert to BaseEntity<System.Guid>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, guid

I'm making an mvc app with .net core and I'm stuck. In my backoffice there is a problem with my delete because of a guid issue. My variable 'model' gives the issue:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Overnight.Models.Security.ApplicationRole' to 'Overnight.Models.BaseEntity'

the code in my RoleController.cs:

```
[HttpGet("[area]/[controller]/[action]/{id:Guid}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(Guid id, [FromQuery] ActionType actionType)
        {
            var model = await ApplicationDbContext.Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if(model == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var viewModel = new ActionRoleViewModel()
            {
                //error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Overnight.Models.Security.ApplicationRole' to 'Overnight.Models.BaseEntity<System.Guid>'
                BaseEntity = model,
                ActionType = actionType
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

this is my BaseEntity.cs:

```
namespace Overnight.Models
{
    public class BaseEntity<T> : IBaseEntity<T>
    {
        public T Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> DeletedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my ActionRoleViewModel.cs :

```
namespace Overnight.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ActionRoleViewModel : ActionBaseEntityViewModel<Guid>
    {
    }
}
```

This is my ApplicationRole.cs :

```
namespace Overnight.Models.Security
{
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
    {
        public DateTime CreatedAt {get; set;}
        public Nullable<DateTime> UpdatedAt {get; set;}
        public Nullable<DateTime> DeletedAt {get; set;}      
    }
}
```

I tried making different BaseEntities where I put Guid instead of T but I keep having the same error

**EDIT:**

this is my ActionBaseEntityViewModel.cs :

```
namespace Overnight.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ActionBaseEntityViewModel<T>: ActionViewModel
    {
        public BaseEntity<T> BaseEntity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `ActionBaseEntityViewModel`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I edited my post with the definition

Comment: What is the definition of `IdentityRole<T>`?

Comment: that represents a role in the identity system. The type is used for the primary key for the role. it comes with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just as the error states. You are trying to set `ActionRoleViewModel.BaseEntity` to `ApplicationRole`, but `ApplicationRole` does not inherit from BaseEntity, so they are incompatible.

You could modify  your `ActionRoleViewModel.BaseEntity` property to be of type `IBaseEntity<T>`, and add the interface to your `ApplicationRole`. This would create the necessary inheritance.

So your `ActionBaseEntityViewModel` would look like this:

```
public class ActionBaseEntityViewModel<T>: ActionViewModel
{
    public IBaseEntity<T> BaseEntity { get; set; }
}
```

And your ApplicationRole would look like this:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>, IBaseEntity<Guid>
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt {get; set;}
    public Nullable<DateTime> UpdatedAt {get; set;}
    public Nullable<DateTime> DeletedAt {get; set;}      
}
```

Comment: thank you, this fixed the error in my code but when I delete a role in my backoffice it gives the error: Type 'Overnight.Models.IBaseEntity`1[System.Guid]' does not have a default constructor

Comment: If you could share the calling code to your delete method and the signature, I could probably be more help.  Just taking a stab in the dark, you can't pass the interface to Entity Framework, it needs a concrete object. Again, I'm making a lot of assumptions here, but storing/passing your ActionBaseEntityViewModel.BaseEntity as ApplicationRole may fix your problem:
`public class ActionBaseEntityViewModel<T>: ActionViewModel
{
    public ApplicationRole BaseEntity { get; set; }
}`